# Qual tipo de dados utilizar ao armazenar dados comprimidos no SQL Server nvarchar(max) ou varbinary(max)?

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, modelagem

Estou trabalhando com SQL Server e preciso armazenar dados de texto que excedem o limite de 8000 bytes (veja a referencia [neste link](http://www.macoratti.net/11/03/sql_nv1.htm)) para uma coluna do SQL Server 2019.

Para reduzir o impacto do armazenamento, resolvemos utilizar a compressão GZip para comprimir os dados e após aplicar a compressão usando gzip, ainda estamos obtendo dados com tamanho superior a 8Kb.

Abaixo código de compressão e descompressão:

```
public static byte[] Zip(string uncompressed)
{
    byte[] ret;
    using (var outputMemory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gz = new GZipStream(outputMemory, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(gz, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                sw.Write(uncompressed);
            }
        }
        ret = outputMemory.ToArray();
    }
    return ret;
}

public static string Unzip(byte[] compressed)
{
    string ret = null;
    using (var inputMemory = new MemoryStream(compressed))
    {
        using (var gz = new GZipStream(inputMemory, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(gz, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                ret = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Com base neste método, caso seja necessário eu posso armazenar os dados como string, usando `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);` .

A minha dúvida maior é qual tipo de dados devo armazenar no SQL, se armazeno a informação como um `byte[]` usando a coluna `varbinary(max)` ou armazeno os dados como string usando a coluna `nvarchar(max)`.

Qual tipo de coluna melhor atende o meu caso? e qual pode gerar um custo menor de armazenamento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta simples para a pergunta é que você vai armazenar *bytes*, então nem pode pensar em `nvarchar`, ainda que funcione, este tipo foi feito para armazenar textos, não faz o menor sentido guardar *bytes* nele, mesmo que seja mais eficiente em espaço, e é tão irrisório perto do todo que não faz sentido fazer essa economia (economizaria por volta de uns 5 *bytes* em 8KB).

Quando você comprime o texto não tem mais um texto, tem um dado binário. Texto tem uma semântica específica que é perdida na compressão, é outro formato de dados. Inclusive faria menos sentido ainda usar o `nvarchar` do que o `varchar` porque o que ele faz justamente é usar uma semântica mais específica ainda, que seria perdida.

Se precisa manter a semântica do texto para efetuar *queries*, então use `nvarchar` (o `varchar` pode ser usado em alguns casos) sem a compressão, é quase a única forma de resolver (mostro abaixo outra).

Pode ver na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) os limites de forma oficial.

Nenhum problema em querer economizar espaço, mas precisa pensar se isso é tão importante.

Se a compressão ajuda, então seria bom pensar na possibilidade de [fazer o banco de dados comprimido como um todo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e de forma transparente e jogar fora todos esses penduricalhos. Isto tem prós e contras, mas costuma ser melhor que comprimir manualmente em qualquer caso.

Comment: Valeu @Maniero, vc é o cara. Eu tava pensando por esse lado mesmo, mais queria me embasar na escolha. Comprimir o banco todo não é o ideal neste momento, devido a uma necessidade específica do projeto, como não precisamos manter a semântica dos dados varbinary atende.